# Filtering and Auditing Intermediate Counts in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-emr, apache-spark-dataset

I've started working on code with the following structure spread out over several classes:

```
var data1 = sparkSession.read().parquet("s3a://....");
log.info(..., data1.count())

var data2 = data1.filter(....)
log.info(..., data2.count())

var data3 = data2.filter(....)
log.info(..., data3.count())

var data4 = firstSubset(data3).union(secondSubset(data3))
log.info(...., data4.count())

data4.foreachPartition(... code to write to SQS ....)
```

where `firstSubset()` and `secondSubset()` do more filtering/counting, and one of them joins to another parquet file loaded from S3 for filtering via an inner join. The code is implemented in Java on Amazon EMR with Spark 2.4, with the data consisting of Spark `Dataset<Row>` objects. The intention is to keep track of what effect each filter has on the original data.

This code takes unreasonably long (~10 minutes) for a very small number of rows running locally. I am new to Spark, but my understanding is that every time we have an action like `.count()`, Spark is creating an execution plan and running it - leading to repeated data loading, work, and shuffling between the nodes.

I have these questions:

1. Is my understanding of how Spark must re-do the work leading up to every count correct?
2. Would this cause the data to be downloaded multiple times?
3. Is there a more efficient mechanism in Spark for finding multiple outputs (i.e., the partial counts) from the same dataset like this? It seems intuitive to me that this could be done with a single pass of the data if it wasn't for the join with another parquet file.
4. Is there another approach in Spark for getting the counts of intermediate results?

Answer (score 0):

1. Spark can find ways to cache intermediate results, but in principle you may be executing everything from the start, including the download.
2. Your code describes a data graph: A recipe of steps (like filter) to arrive at a result. A result would be a count. Every time you call count, Spark has to execute the recipe to find the answer. That's why `data2 = data1.filter(...)` can return immediately but `data2.count()` takes time.
3. And 4. Yes. Have a look at caching, for example `data2.cache()` should help.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Can you provide a link to the documentation for snapshots? My googling is only resulting in pages referencing snapshot versions of Spark.

Comment: Sorry, it's not called snapshotting in Spark, it's called caching. I updated my answer.